# Excel web part from list - Autorefresh

Tags: excel, web

I am using SharePoint 2010.

I currently have a list that gets updated many times throughout the day.

I currently have an Excel Web Part with graphs and summary tables on the first tab, and its data source on a second tab. On the second tab, the data source comes from a .iqy file that links to the SharePoint list.

Here's my issue: In order to update the source, I am having to manually download the file, refresh the data, and re-upload it to SharePoint.

Is there a way to make this data update every 15 minutes or so? Can I add some kind of button that would refresh the data source?

My initial research has suggested this:

- Use PowerPivot (not an option, I am in a corporate environment and
  can't install it)
- Use the SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) to    query the
  SharePoint list, and deploy the SSRS report to SharePoint    library

Maybe another approach may be better. I appreciate any advice in advance. Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the XSLTListViewWebPart (The one you see on AllItems.aspx)? This one support autorefresh through ajax

Answer (score 1):

Refeshing data from SharePoint list using data query is not supported in Excel Services.

Look at the list of unsupported features for Excel Services ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823.aspx)

I know the list is for MOSS 2007, however the only thing Microsoft changed is that they don't block workbook rendering in SP2010 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595319.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have an article that shows you how to do this.

http://learn.sharepoint.com

exact article is [here](https://learn.sharepoint.com/Blog/_layouts/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/Blog/Blog%20Post%20Documents/Excel%20Services%20with%20SharePoint%20List%20Data.docx&action=default&Source=https://learn.sharepoint.com/Blog/Blog%2520Post%2520Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon%252EDocument&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence&DefaultItemOpen=1)

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: The solution suggested by user1944 only works on premises, if you have access to the SharePoint server.  OP certainly can't use it.