# Automaticly update connected excel file when a new item is added to a sharepoint list

Tags: excel

I have a sharepoint list that we update daily and it is connected to an excel file that we update manualy. So what I would like is when a new item is added to the list it automatically updates the excel file.

Comment: Where the excel files resides?

Comment: How did you connect the file and the list? Excel services?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements there may be no way. You can use Refresh on open or periodic refresh:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/refresh-external-data-in-excel-services-HA010105474.aspx

Have a look also at these threads:
[Excel web part from list - Autorefresh](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45549/excel-web-part-from-list-autorefresh)
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/258013dc-2687-486c-8d87-3834e25bf0f4/how-to-autorefresh-pivot-table-in-excel-web-access-webpart-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Check also the supported connections and scenarios: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/work-with-external-data-in-excel-services-sharepoint-server-HA102830785.aspx

*From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026599/sharepoint-online-and-refreshing-excel-files/22064048#22064048*